# Having trouble with jquery-smooth-scroll-rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-plugins

I added this to my Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-smooth-scroll-rails', :git => 'git@github.com:gretel/jquery-smooth-scroll-rails.git'
end
```

Then I ran `bundle install` and included the following in my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery-smooth-scroll
```

And this is how I'm calling it in my `custom.js` file:

```
 $('a.scroll-to-form').smoothScroll();
```

which is referencing the element created by this tag:

```
<%= link_to "See your options", "#bottom-form", :class=>"white-btn scroll-to-form" %>
```

But the effect isn't being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and couldn't make it work with the gem you are using with rails 4, but it is working nicely if i add directly the js file from the github directory.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll/master/jquery.smooth-scroll.js

Did you put custom.js after jquery-smooth-scroll ? Javascript need to loaded in the correct order, but if it was not in correct order you see would some errors in the javascript console.
If you keep the //=require tree . in application.js it is very possible custom.js is being put before jquery smooth scroll.

Maybe you should use this snippet to make sure the the javascript is being executed once the page has been rendered in custom.js:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $('.scroll-to-form').click("on", function(e) {
      return $(this).smoothScroll({
        speed: 2000
      });
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```